# Avatar the Last Airbender graphic novels

Tags: suggested-order, avatar-the-last-airbender

Can anyone tell me the names of the graphic novels in order?

I have googled it but I keep getting different answers

Comment: By 'in order', do you mean publication order, or in universe chronological order?

Comment: Preferably chronologically as it corresponds to events

Comment: And are you concerned specifically only with any version? There was stuff released around the time of the movie that was actually intended as a prequel for the movie, but does not contradict anything from the show.

Comment: I wasn't aware there were different versions, what's the difference?

Comment: Some material (books, comics/manga) was released specifically tied to the movie released a few years ago. It doesn't contradict the show, but I'm not 100% sure if it's what was in the minds of the creators.

Comment: so for arguments sake let's say I don't care to read the ones directly related to the movie or leading up to The movie, what would the order be?

Comment: http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender_comics

Answer (score 2):

### Before the Show (Non-canon)

[Zuko's Story](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Film:The_Last_Airbender_Prequel:_Zuko%27s_Story), which is intended to be a prequel to both the TV show and the M. Night Shyamalan film, tells the story of Zuko after his banishment, but before he met Aang. The characters have their film appearance, except for characters not in the film (like Ty Lee and Guru Pathik) who have their show appearance. While it doesn't conflict with anything in the show, it is considered non-canon.

### During the Show

There is only one graphic novel that takes place during the show:

- [The Lost Adventures](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender_comics#The_Lost_Adventures) (a trade paperback collection of individual comics from *Nick Magazine*)

To my knowledge, these comics are stand-alone and are not mentioned in the graphic novels that take place after the show.

### After the Show

The rest of the graphic novels continue the story after the show ended. They take place in publication order, and occasionally reference or build on events and side characters from previous graphic novels. Each of them is a trilogy consisting of three 80 page paperback books:

1. [The Promise](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Promise)
2. [The Search](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Search)
3. [The Rift](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rift)
4. [Smoke and Shadow](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Smoke_and_Shadow) (Part 3 coming in April 2016)
5. [North and South](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/North_and_South) (Part 1 coming in September 2016)

If you are a completionist, there are several comics that were released after *The Lost Adventures* during Free Comic Book Day, and have not yet been collected into a trade paperback.

1. [Rebound](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Rebound) (Free Comic Book Day 2013)

   - Takes place some time after *The Promise* and before *Smoke and Shadow*
2. [Shells](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Shells) (Free Comic Book Day 2014)
3. [Sisters](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Sisters) (Free Comic Book Day 2015)

*Shells* and *Sisters* do not have clues as to when they take place, except that it is after the end of the show.

Comment: Would be great if you could add Korra comics as bonus!

Comment: @CreationEdge The only Korra books out there are art books. Dark Horse has [announced](http://comicsalliance.com/legend-of-korra-comic-artwork/) that they *are* going to create a Korra comic continuation, but thus far they haven't revealed a name, plot, or release date.

Comment: Oh man, I thought it was out already. Harrumph!

Answer (score -1):

Each comic book story has three parts, much like the shows were split into three parts. The stories are listed below, in order:

- *Avatar The Last Airbender: The Promise*
- *Avatar The Last Airbender: The Search*
- *Avatar The Last Airbender: The Rift*
- *Avatar The Last Airbender: Smoke And Shadow*
- *Avatar The Last Airbender: North And South*
- *Avatar The Last Airbender: Imbalance*